# I got 404 error after sending POST method from ajax (@ResponseStatus & ResponseEntity)

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, http

I ma using Spring MVC and trying to use jQuery. I have this on my web page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var entity = {mag: "status_key", paper: "View10"};
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajaxJsonPost",
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(entity),
            contentType: 'application/json',
        });
    });
});
```

Spring server has this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "ajaxJsonPost", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void postJson(@RequestBody Entity en) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("writing entity: " + en.toString());
}
```

OK, Entity cames to server. BUT  browser console prints *`404 not found`*. I know that my POST request needs any response. In the Internet I've found solution which recommends me to return ResponseEntity object, OR use annotation @ResponseStatus. They both return HttpStatus well, but I don't know in which cases I should use them.  What is the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/apipath")
public class SomeController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajaxJsonPost", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String postJson(@RequestBody final Entity en) {
        System.out.println(en.toString());

        //assuming you have a class "EntityService" and 
        //it has a method postData 
        //which takes Entity object as parameter and pushes into database.
        EntityService.postData(en);

        System.out.println("added");
        return "success";
    }
}
```

Entity object on the Server side

```
@JsonAutoDetect
public class Entity {

    private String mag;
    private String paper;

    public String getMag() {
        return mag;
    }

    public void setMag(final String mag) {
        this.mag = mag;
    }

    public String getPaper() {
        return paper;
    }
    public void setPaper(final String paper)
        this.paper = paper;
    }
}
```

ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var entity = {mag: "status_key", paper: "View10"};
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/apipath/ajaxJsonPost",
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(entity),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success : function(response) {    
                  alert(response);
            },
            error : function() {
                  alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And as far as why and when to use @ResponseStatus and @ResponseEntity, there is already a short and simple answer here by @Sotirios Delimanolis. [When use @ResponseEntity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26550981/3617752) .

It says :

> **ResponseEntity** is meant to represent the entire HTTP response. You can
>   control anything that goes into it: status code, headers, and body.
>
> **@ResponseBody** is a marker for the HTTP response body and
>   **@ResponseStatus** declares the status code of the HTTP response.
>
> **@ResponseStatus** isn't very flexible. It marks the entire method so you
>   have to be sure that your handler method will always behave the same
>   way. And you still can't set the headers. You'd need the
>   HttpServletResponse or a HttpHeaders parameter.
>
> **Basically, ResponseEntity lets you do more.**

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I think I don't need to learn ne annotation. I just want to know what is the difference between @ResponseStatus & ResponseEntity

Comment: Yeah! It helps! Please make your comment as answer. I'll accept it!