# ExceptionHandler invokes but doesn't affect http response

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception, exceptionhandler

I have the following method:

```
    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidPriceUpdateException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public String handleInvalidPriceUpdateException(InvalidPriceUpdateException e) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new HttpErrorDTO(e.getMessage()));
    }
```

I see(in debug) that it invokes but in browser I see 500 error(instead of HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST). and content of http response contains exception info(instead of `HttpErrorDTO` structure).

What wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are returning a `String`, where you should really be building the entire `ResponseEntity`. Have a read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549379/when-use-responseentityt-and-restcontroller-for-spring-restful-applications) on what that means and how to build one for example.