# What's the difference between return type of ResponseEntity<> and simple object (ex. User) in REST Spring Java?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm new to REST and I'm making simple REST application with users and articles. I wonder what's the difference between two samples below:

```
@GetMapping("/user/{id}")
public User getUserById(PathVariable("id") String id) {
 .....
 return userService.getUserById();
}
```

and

```
@GetMapping("/user/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<User> getUserById(PathVariable("id") String id) {
 .....
  return new ResponseEntity<> ....
}
```

Which one is better to use?
And what's the main difference between two of them?

Comment: `ResponseEntity` allows specifying a responseCode  code, headers,  so it might be more flexible if there is need to return something more specific beside `HTTP 200 ok`

Comment: you can look at this question also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549379/when-use-responseentityt-and-restcontroller-for-spring-restful-applications

Comment: the bottom line is if there is a need in flexibility (header, status)  `ResponseEntity` is handy, if on other side there is a need to just return an object with `200 OK`, there is no need to use it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ResponseEntity is containing the entire HTTP response that returns as a response which gives the flexibility to add headers, change status code and do similar things to the response.

Another hand sending PJO class directly like returning users in the example is somewhat similar to `return ResponseEntity.ok(user)` which responded to user details successfully to the user. But the ability to change headers, status codes is not available if you return PJO directly.

It is good to use ResponseEntity over PJO when there is a scenario you need to change the headers or you need to change status according to the result.

eg: show not found when there is no data you can `return ResponseEntity.status(404).body(<-body->)`.

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted to hear, thank you so much! Now I can see this difference, good job!

Answer (score 2):

at least in the Response Entity, you can set the http status and you can use ResponseEntity<?> where ? is generic any object its very convenient to use